# How to create own reusable attributes for a button component like ex. fab, dark, small, color="primary" of vuetify without using vuetity in vue .js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, tailwind-css

I have created a button component  as a reusable component which I want to replace with all the HTML buttons in my project.
I want the same button to display in primary color, same in danger, disabled, etc.
Same button for rounded with desired svg icons inside it something similar to vuetify.

```
<v-btn
  class="mx-2"
  fab
  dark
  small
  color="primary"
>
```

I want to pass value to property color for example color=" danger" rather than typing the entire CSS and the red button should reflect. I also want to know how to create attributes like fab, small, etc so that I can design them for my button . I am using tailwind CSS for my project. I tried creating a parent component that passed the above values as props and used style and class binding, but nothing seems to work. I want to know how to do it with just one sample code for the button, that would be a great help.

Button component

```
 <template>
<button :type="type" :class="primary" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:ring focus:ring-gray-300 disabled:opacity-25 transition">
    <slot></slot>
</button>
```

import { defineComponent, ref , methods} from 'vue'

    export default defineComponent({
        setup() {

            const primary = ref('bg-blue-500')            
            const error = ref('bg-red-500')            
            return{
                primary
            }
        }
    })

Comment: It's called directives, see docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: I am using Vue 3, it is slightly different. I'll go through it

Comment: Or you can do like so: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-sammet-ce9yf?file=/src/components/AppButton.vue

Comment: for ur above code from sandbox i want to know , how can I pass <my-btn color="success"> while using this component as reusable solt

Comment: `color` is one of props what can be defined on `my-btn` component and based on value (ex: `success` will have class `btn-success-class`)

Comment: I've made changes to example, check.